# How to divide service charges between partners

Tags: numerical-methods

I received $2600.

$1800 made with a partnership project.

$800 made with my personal project.

$80 I paid service charges to a company.

How do divide service charges($80) between me and my partner?

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted (other than the fact that this is not numerical methods) so I'll give you an upvote. It is clear that you work in industry and don't have a math background, so I think it's a perfectly fair question. My question is how are you splitting your partnership project money?

Comment: Not sure :)
Thank you so much for understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you agree with your partner you get $x$% from1800 dollars  from the joint project and the service charge is proportional to income , you pay $A=80\cdot \frac{800+1800\cdot 0.01\cdot x}{1800+800}$dollars ,your partner pays 80-$A$ dollars.

In the case $x=50$ , you pay $80\cdot \frac{800+900}{1800+800}=52.31$ dollars ,your partner pays 27.69 dollars.

Comment: Thank you so much @BStar for the help